# FTE agent running but not transferring files

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

My WebSphere MQ FTE agent was running but it is not transferring files.  When I run `fteShowAgentDetails` I found 300 transfer IDs as queued.

Ex:

```
Source Transfer States:
    TransferId                                          State
    414d51204d514654455030332020202050941b672de19510    queued
```

When I restarted the agent it didn't recover any old files but is transferring new files.  How can I monitor agent status if its transferring files or not?

Answer (score 0):

All file transfers occur between two agent endpoints.  These may be the same agent but typically the endpoints are different agents.  Unfortunately, the question doesn't mention the status of the second agent in the pair so we do not know whether it is capable of participating in the transfer.

We also do not know whether the agents are transferring many files in a single batch.  Assuming that the two agents are both capable of transferring, the `Queued` status normally indicates that a large batch is processing with some number of files currently in transfer and some number of them queued awaiting their turn.  Normally these can be seen completing and the queue of pending transfers tapering down to zero over time.

It sounds as though the files that are queued are simply waiting their turn as part of a large batch.

Comment: Thanks for reply .. to answer your question both source and destination agent endpoints are running & I'm transferring one file at a time. If we keep receiving new file it piles-up everything & change source agent status to unreachable.